# Problem with Java Binary I/O

Tags: java, collections, io

Alright, so I'm trying to write a bunch of Sudoku puzzles to a file. This is the code I have to generate the puzzles. gen is the class that generates the puzzles, gridArray is an object array that will hold the puzzles (The puzzles are generated as two-dimensional int arrays). The System.out.print just prints the grid to ensure that the puzzles are valid. The problem I have is stated below the code block:

```
public void run(){
    ObjectOutputStream output;
    try {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));

        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            int[][] blahbot = gen.generate(difficulty);
            gridArray[i] = blahbot;
            System.out.println(" #" + (i + 1) + " ");
            for(int row = 0; row < 9; row++){
                for(int col = 0; col < 9; col++){
                    System.out.print(blahbot[row][col]);
                    if(col == 8){
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        output.writeObject(gridArray);
        output.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

The output writes the entire object array to file. The problem I have is that every time I read the array from the file, it always returns a single puzzle. I have the read program printing out the entire content of the array and it's the same puzzle, although the length of the array is correct.

I made this part print out the arrays as they were saved, and those were correct (No repeats). I'm running out of things to test.. I even tried using different collections classes to save, and I came up with the same result. Can anyone see what's wrong with my code?

Here is the read portion of my code:

```
try{
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        try{
            while (true){
                try {
                    gridArray = (Object[]) input.readObject();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                } 
            }
        }catch(EOFException e){
        }

        /*
         * Close the input stream
         */
        input.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    for(Object array: gridArray){
        int[][] temp = (int[][])array;
        for(int row = 0; row < 9; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < 9; col++){
                System.out.print(temp[row][col]);
                if(col == 8){
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

Where r is a Random. It reads the Object array from the file then it casts each Object as an int[][] to print out. The print is just a test to see the contents of the array.

Comment: How are you reading them back in?

Comment: Let's see the read portion of the code.

Comment: ... and have you examined output to determine if generator is creating different puzzles on each run?

Comment: Is `gen.generate(difficulty)` creating a `new int[][]`, or is it using the same `int[][]` for every run? The latter could cause the problems you are describing.

Comment: I have posted the read portion of the code.

Andy, I have examined the output of the code that generates the puzzles and each of them is unique. I have also tested the array blahbot to determine its contents before writing it to file and the puzzles are unique. Titan: gen is creating a new int[][] every time. I tested it with a different driver before I created the Thread that runs the puzzle generation code above.

Comment: Storing a primitive type array `int[][] blahbot` in an Object array `Object[] gridArray` seems problematic to me.

Comment: @Claude: that should actually be fine.  An `int[][]` is an `Object`, after all.  An `Object[]` can store many `int[][]` just fine.

Comment: I don't know if this holds any significance, but the puzzle that is repeated over and over in the file is the last puzzle generated.

Comment: @SkylineAddict, are you getting 1 puzzle read, or n copies of the same puzzle? <p> The original writer code above shows a single writeObject() call of the array of int[][]s. By any chance has that call moved into the loop? <p> BTW, the "if(col==8)" is unnecessary - you can just include its statement after the inner loop.

Comment: The if(col == 8) is just there to make the grid print out in actual grid form (9x9). The writeObject is called outside of the loop. My reader is finding an array of the original length, but it only contains duplicates of the last puzzle that was generated. It's really strange because if I test the contents before the writeObject, it contains unique puzzles, but if I test it after the the write, it contains duplicates of the same puzzle.

Comment: When you tested it before writeObject(), did you do that in the same loop as the call to generate()? If so, try moving your test outside the loop. (This will be easiest if you refactor the output code into another method accepting the whole gridArray.) I will be surprised if you're not. <p> You can print in grid form without the "if(col==8)" test.

Comment: I used different loops for the test and took the main loop out of the try blocks and it still yielded the same result. Are you suggesting that I create a whole new method that contains anything to do with I/O?

Comment: I'm just fishing here, but it sounds like maybe you're not getting a fresh array from each call to `gen.generate`.  Does the generate method create a new array (`new int[9][9]`)?

Comment: @SkylineAddict - To narrow down the source of the problem, I'm suggesting this: debugPrint(gridArray); \ output.writeObject(gridArray); \ output.close(); \ debugPrint(gridArray) -- after the "for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++)" generation loop in the writer. If you get different results for the two debug prints, it means Java's writeObject() is flawed.  But if you get the same result -- identical puzzles -- both before and after, it means the problem is before writeObject(). If so, generate() is the likely culprit.

Comment: I found what was wrong and it was exactly what you said. The program was not creating a new int[][] every time it generated. I added a clear method that made new int[][]'s every time it generated and it created unique solutions. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code shown, it would appear that you are returning the same int[][] instance for every call to gen.generate().  If this method is reusing the int[][] that was created from a previous invocation, then you will be, in actuality, be adding the same int[][] to the array everytime.  The subsequent calls to the generate method will result in modifying the arrays you added to your list of arrays.

Example of what could be happening:

```
private int[][]data = new int[9][9];
public int[][] generate() {
   // add logic here to set values in data array
   return data;
}
```

If your method is similar to above, then you will have the problem you documented.  You should create a new instance of the int[][] array everytime you call the method or change the way you are writing the data to the file.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of testing, try changing this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
    int[][] blahbot = gen.generate(difficulty);
    gridArray[i] = blahbot;
    System.out.println(" #" + (i + 1) + " ");
    for(int row = 0; row < 9; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < 9; col++){
            System.out.print(blahbot[row][col]);
            if(col == 8){
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
output.writeObject(gridArray);
output.close();
```

To this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
    output.writeObject(gen.generate(difficulty));
    output.flush();
}
output.close();
```

If things suddenly work better, the results point towards what ILMTitan mentioned in his comment -- you would need to use the `new` keyword and actually return a `new int[9][9]` from your `generate` method rather than reusing whatever reference it's returning.